# Page doesn't scroll in Chrome on iOS

Tags: html, ios, css, google-chrome, scroll

I have this really weird problem. Our Tumblr blog home page http://blog.wigo.us doesn't scroll in Chrome on iOS. It scrolls just fine in any browser on desktop, any browser on Android and in Safari on iOS. But the latest version of Chrome in iOS8 just refuses to scroll the page.

The effect is basically like somebody put overflow:hidden on body element and gave it width=100%, height=100%. I looked through CSS of the theme and didn't find anything suspicious. I even run iPhone emulation in Google Developer tools - everything works just fine.

It would be awesome if someone had a similar problem and could point me in the right direction.